# react-router V5 preserving the query params while navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i have a datatable and a pagination component every time change the page the query-parameters are added to the url like: /table?pageNo:2 as soon as i go to different page it loses the query-params i want while coming back from any component it should show the same url like: table/?pageNo:2